# IONIC back button not working at any case

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I trying to use [ionic-back-button](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/back-button). When the app loads I am redirected to account page which is `core.page.ts`. In this page I have two button with routerlink login and sign up. When I click login button in core.page.html I get redirected to login page. The back button also appears. But when click on that back button it does nothing except that ripple effect. Am not sure why. Please help.

In my app.routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'account',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'account',
    loadChildren: () => import('./core/core.module').then( m => m.CorePageModule)
  }
];
```

In my core.routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CorePage
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterComponent
  },
];
```

in my core.page.html

```
<div class="button_wrap">
  <ion-button color="success" [routerLink]="['/account/register']"  expand="block">Sign Up</ion-button>
  <ion-button color="light" [routerLink]="['/account/login']"  expand="block">Log In</ion-button>
</div>
```

In my login page

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button defaultHref="/" icon="chevron-back-outline" text="Back"></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>LOGIN</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <p> login works! </p>

</ion-content>
```

Similar stories mentioned here but no exact solution.

[Ionic Framework Forum 1](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-back-button-does-nothing/193733/2)

[Ionic Framework Forum 2](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-back-button-not-working/183733/8)

Answer (score 2):

working very well on ionic 5, to make a button go back to the previous page
**Step 1:**
on your .ts file import this

```
import { IonRouterOutlet } from '@ionic/angular';
```

**Step 2:**
add it to your constructor on the .ts file

```
constructor( private routerOutlet: IonRouterOutlet ) { }
```

**Step 3:**
define go back function

```
 goBack() { this.routerOutlet.pop(); }
```

**Step 4:**
use it in your .html file

```
<ion-icon (click)="goBack()" slot="start" name="arrow-back-outline"></ion-icon>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this,it resloved my problem:

```
<ion-back-button text="返回" (click)="pop()"></ion-back-button>
import {NavController} from '@ionic/angular';
export class XXComponent{
constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {}
  async pop() {
    await this.navCtrl.pop();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution for this scenario but it does work with smooth animation.

```
<ion-back-button (click)="goBack()"></ion-back-button>

import { IonRouterOutlet } from '@ionic/angular';
goBack() {
    this.routerOutlet.pop();
}
```

[back button hack source code link](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/f58424f62596b9eb82bebb8e07c211e1725c025a/angular/src/directives/navigation/ion-back-button.ts)

[Credit link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-back-button-does-nothing/193733/2)

Answer (score 0):

you can assign 'root' as routerDirection on back-button:

```
<ion-button class="root" routerLink="/home" routerDirection="root">Home</ion-button>
```

When you want go go back to previous page use:

```
back(): void {
    this.router.navigate("..");
}
```

It seems your code with defaultHref

```
<ion-back-button defaultHref="/"
```

is not working here, replace it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I am wondering why that `ion back button` displays but doesn't function ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button defaultHref="home"></ion-back-button>
</ion-buttons>
```

You will have to provide the page URL.

Comment: If I navigate from home page to login page the back button should work which is not working. even if I add defaultHref its not working either with url or anything.

Comment: Please check routing path.

Comment: I did. I checked using multiple paths and set them to default route. None of them are working. I have also provided the link for similar stories. Please check.

Comment: Can You please update your code above, so that I can check? because its working fine in my system, the Configuration of my project is:  Ionic CLI: 6.13.1 Ionic Framework: @ionic/angular 5.5.4